# prevent from zoom in webview when using searchview

Tags: android, webview, searchview

I want to use a `searchView` to search in `webview` , when I search in it, webview has change and zoom in heppeninig, I use webView for showing epub book in it I showed more detail in two screenshot(after, before) and paste my code here
MY android Device os is Android Kitkat
[image: ScreenShot (Normal state)]

[image: ScreenShot(when Use Search]

more detail in code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_reader, menu);
        this.menu = menu;

        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if (!query.isEmpty()) {
                    searchEnabled = true;
                    if (!flag) {
                        webView.findAllAsync(query);

                        flag = true;
                        try {
                            Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
                            m.invoke(webView, true);
                        } catch (Throwable ignored) {
                        }
                    } else {
                        webView.findNext(true);
                    }

                    Log.i("webview", webView.getScrollY() + "");

                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                if (newText.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                        Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
                        m.invoke(webView, false);
                    } catch (Throwable ignored) {
                    }
                }
                flag = false;
                return true;
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {

                try {
                    Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
                    m.invoke(webView, false);
                } catch (Throwable ignored) {
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling automatic zoom of webview:

```
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
```